Flutter iOS: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleSignIn
I recently had to update a flutter project and a a result, completely broke the dependency tree on iOS.
The original error message displays the following:
Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
  pod repo update

After running that followed by pod install. I get the following message:
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleSignIn":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    GoogleSignIn (= 7.0.0, ~> 7.0)

  In Podfile:
    google_sign_in_ios (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in_ios/darwin`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GoogleSignIn (~> 7.1)

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleSignIn":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    GoogleSignIn (= 7.0.0, = 7.1)

  In Podfile:
    google_sign_in_ios (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in_ios/darwin`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GoogleSignIn (~> 7.1)


You have either:
 * changed the constraints of dependency `GoogleSignIn` inside your development pod `google_sign_in_ios`.
   You should run `pod update GoogleSignIn` to apply changes you've made.

And after updating that pod, I get the same error with a different pod or I just end up getting the same message.
this is my pubspec.yaml

# Prevent accidental publishing to pub.dev.
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.1 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  auth_repository:
    path: packages/auth_repository
  form_inputs:
    path: packages/form_inputs
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  qr_flutter: ^4.1.0
  firebase_core: ^2.15.1
  mobile_scanner: ^3.5.5
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.4.9 # Use the latest version
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.8
  google_sign_in: ^6.2.1
  sign_in_with_apple: ^5.0.0
  image_picker: ^1.0.8
  firebase_messaging: ^14.7.19
  cloud_firestore: ^4.15.8
  json_annotation: ^4.8.1
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.1.0
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^2.0.1
  bloc: ^8.1.4
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.5
  flow_builder: ^0.1.0
  formz: ^0.6.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.7.0
  easy_search_bar: ^2.5.0
  date_picker_plus: ^4.0.0
  flutter_typeahead: ^5.2.0
  multi_select_flutter: ^4.1.3
  bloc_test: ^9.1.7
  intl: 0.19.0
  http: ^1.2.0
  mockito: ^5.4.4
  objectid: ^3.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.3.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  test: ^1.24.9
  build_runner: ^2.4.12

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  # Enable generation of localized Strings from arb files.
  generate: true

  assets:
    # Add assets from the images directory to the application.
    - assets/images/
    - .env


Try changing the minimum iOS version to 11 in your Podfile.
